# Fill Cell of column DataGrid with join

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

i need fill cell of this Colmun in datagrid wpf . i create a join with Linq :

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AnbarDari.Model.AnbarDB db = new Model.AnbarDB();
        var qProduct = db.Tbl_Products.ToList();
        var qUserPro = (from a in db.Tbl_User
                        join r in db.Tbl_Products on a.UserID equals r.UserID
                        select a.Name).ToString();
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = qProduct;
    }
```

i want show name of user with `qUserPro`. how fill this :

[image]

Comment: Please see [mcve]. It's hard to read the arabic letters ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your join is assigned to the variable qUserPro. This variable is never used.

Change from `ItemsSource = qProduct;` to `ItemsSource = qUserPro;`

You may also want to show more values than just the name:

```
var qUserPro = from a in db.Tbl_User
join r in db.Tbl_Products on a.UserID equals r.UserID
select a.Name, a.ArabicLettersICannotRead;
```